# What's the point of a `.inc` file in C++ & C? What situation would you want to use it?

Tags: c++, c

I'm sure this is has been asked before and will be closed and marked as a duplicate but I'm having problems finding it...

For example, at `llvm/lib/Support/Unix/Signals.inc` within the llvm project. What's the point of using this suffix for a cpp file?

Comment: It's almost certainly a file that should be included in some other file, but it is not a regular header file, so the `.h` extension is not appropriate.  Judging from the name, I'd guess it contains initializers for an array of signal numbers and names that was generated by preprocessing a header file.

Comment: It would be sensible to provide a link to the file (in GitHub or in the LLVM project's source repository) so people can find the file more easily.  It's a nuisance to have to guess where to go.

Comment: One view of the file can be found from [https://llvm.org/viewvc/llvm-project/llvm/trunk/lib/Support/Unix/Signals.inc?view=log](https://llvm.org/viewvc/llvm-project/llvm/trunk/lib/Support/Unix/Signals.inc?view=log) — this shows the change log, but you can click onto any version.  It seems my guess about what it contains was off-track; it contains more code than just initializers and is not simply a generated file.

Comment: I agree with answers, but missing here some rationale for such files. Generally, header files should contain _interface_ and source files corresponding _implementation_. However, such a distinction is not always feasible, especially with templates. Many templated libraries are _header-only_, such as libraries from Boost or C++ Standard Library. And, simply said, everything has to be then included, both interface and implementation code. In such cases, `.inc` files are intended for implementation code and should not be included directly by library users.

Comment: I'm not all to familiar with unix or linix but from what I can speculate the extension here would be similar to `*.inl` in c++. For example if I'm writing a class template and want to separate the implementations from the declaration where I'm not able to write those functions in a `*.cpp` file what I'll typically do is outside and after the class declaration but before the end of the `header guard` I'll have `#include "classname.inl"` and I'll put my class templates' definitions in the `*.inl` file. I'm guessing that `*.inc` might fall into this category of special `includes`.

Answer (score 13, accepted):

The extension is just a different one than .h or .hpp. I wasn't there when whoever decided to name the file this way. There is no particular reason other than convention that determine extensions in general.

As Jonathan points out, it may be to distinguish it from "regular header files" that are usable anywhere.

The comment above the inclusion of these files is perhaps a reasonable explanation:

```
// Include the platform-specific parts of this class.
#ifdef LLVM_ON_UNIX
#include "Unix/Signals.inc"
#endif
#ifdef LLVM_ON_WIN32
#include "Windows/Signals.inc"
#endif
```

These contain platform specific parts, it is not, as such, a "header-file", it is just a portion of code that is dependent on the target architecture, and someone decided that it's better to have two separate files than to have a huge `#ifdef` in the one source file. [A reasonable decision, in my mind, as the Unix file I looked at is several hundred lines, with further stuff included and some more `#if`]

Answer (score 5):

In the context of llvm .inc files are generated by tablegen files :

https://llvm.org/docs/TableGen/ProgRef.html

So the .inc extension is used to distinguish between auto generated headerfile vs manually written headerfiles.